# Automatically generate assignment variables by Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Say I have a function

```
public List<FileChangedData> GetFileChanging(DateTime startDateTime)
{
...
}
```

If I call the function

```
GetFileChanging(startDate);
```

Is there a way to use resharper to automatically generate the assignment, i.e.,

```
List<FileChangedData> obj=GetFileChanging(startDate);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, kind of... resharper use the `[Pure]` attribute in order to see that specific method returns a value and do nothing else useful.

So you can use the `[Pure]` attribute and reshaper will suggest you to introduce a variable or a field.

Eg.

```
[System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Pure]
public List<FileChangedData> GetFileChanging(DateTime startDateTime)
{
    ...
}
```